# Imap command to fetch mailbox data in bulk

Tags: c#, imap

I am using IMAP commands to fetch the mailbox data. Currently I am fetching mails one by one using mail id. But while reading large mailboxes its very slow.

> IMAP Command:"$ UID FETCH uid body[]\r\n"

Is there any command or way out so that I can fetch bulk data using IMAP command?

Thank you;

Mayuresh.

Comment: Also using threading but still issue with speed.

Comment: Just put a comma separated list of UIDs you're interested in.  $ UID FETCH 1,2,3,74,30 BODY[]\r\n".  This is all very detailed in RFC 3501.

Comment: Thanks Max!!!! Its able to fetch the multiple emails.But still speed is slow. Could you suggest me any changes for the optimization?

Comment: Put up to ~100-200 messages per request, make sure your parser can keep up.  Profile to see where the bottleneck is.  It may not be the network.